# Unable to load downloaded content (CakePHP)

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I tried to download the file uploaded in Cake PHP. I could download it but it says 'Failed to load PDF' for PDF and 'The file is corrupted' for docs. I don't know what is wrong in the code.

Here is the brief code.

```
<?php
header('Content-Length '.$requiredFile['Upload']['size']);
header('Content-type: '.$requiredFile['Upload'['type']]);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$requiredFile['Upload']['name'].'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
echo $requiredFile['Upload']['content'];
?>
```

$requiredFile is an array:

```
Array
(
    [Upload] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [tenant_id] => 29
            [name] => Niraj Paudel (CV).pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [size] => 126626
            [content] => 'content over here'
  )
);
```

I would be very grateful if you guys help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cakephp you can simply download file sending it in response. Suppose your file is uploaded in `webroot/uploads/`, below is sample code that will download file.

```
return $this->response->file(WWW_ROOT.'uploads/yourfilename.pdf', array('download' => true, 'name' => 'yourfilename'));
```

Comment: Actually, I have uploaded file, taken its name, type, size, content and saved it to mysql database table. When I retrieve the data, I have name, type, size and content in $requiredFile array. In this case, how could I use the above code. Thank You in advance.

Comment: You can use this code in function where you retrieving your data. where did you upload your file ?

Comment: I have sent $requiredFile array from controllers action 'downloadFiles' to view 'download_files.ctp'. In 'download_files.ctp', I have used the above mentioned code.

Comment: than add this in your `downloadFiles` action. You don't need to render view. It will simple download file and will show prompt to save file.

Comment: To be frank, I do not know where does the file get saved. What I did was just submit the form containing 'choose file' field, save the file parameters like size, name, content (from tmp_name) and type into database. For downloading, I retrieve the data from database and used the above code. In this scenario, how could I use the above code. Well, I do not much about file uploads. Sorry if I sound crazy. Anyways, I appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: ohh.. you need to save file physically somewhere in server first, only then you can download it later.

Comment: Can't I save the contents into database and retrieve the content from it without saving it to server?